# How to configure Log4j2 Flume appender using system properties

Tags: log4j2, flume

Configuring log4j2's flume appender https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender 
for HA seems like a difficult task if you want a generic file that can be used for different clusters. Each flume 'agent' requires its own line in configuration like

```
<Agent host="192.168.10.101" port="8800"/>
```

How can I specify agents using system property. It is possible to do so. Also, how can redistribute load across all agents.

`LoadBalancingLog4jAppender` - a Log4j compliant appender that flume provides seems to solve the problems I am facing but I am really looking for log4j2 solution